# Html Window: subscribe to the message events of an iframe window element

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know the basic usage of `postMessage` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage when you want to send data to the parent window from an iframe. But is it possible to make this more generic? for example, if in my iframe I publish with `postMessage` on the window object of my iframe, what could prevent the main window to add an event listener on the messages of the iframe. Here is an example :

in a directory tree that look like this:

```
root
  |___ frontpage
  |        |____index.html
  |___ iframe
           |____index.html
```

**the iframe/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>iframe</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
      const trustedOrigins = ["http://localhost:5001"];

      function sendMsg(msg) {
        console.log(`Send message iframe window`, msg);
        window.postMessage(msg, trustedOrigins[0]);
      }
       setInterval(() => { sendMsg("Coucou") }, 5000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Iframe body</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**the main page that embed the iframe : frontpage/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>main</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:5001/index.html"></iframe>

    <script>
      const trustedOrigins = ["http://localhost:5001"];

      function onMsg(msg) {
        console.log(`Message from an iframe`, msg);
      }

      const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
      iframe.onload = () => {
        console.log('Adding event listener on the iframe to catch its messages');
        iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener("message", onMsg, false);
      };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expected to be able to display the messages that the iframe send to itself be nothing is displayed

install http-server to test it `npm install -g http-server`

```
cd frontpage
http-server -p 5000
cd iframe
http-server -p 5001
```

go with a browser to http://localhost:5000 and look at the console messages, the iframe send its messages but the event listener catch any of it.

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) { console.log(event); }, false);
```

Comment: I guess that you suggest that I add an event listener on the window in the iframe page? but I want to add the event listener from the page that load the iframe.